# Cannot see Google Drive from non-SNAP Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-drive

I am running the NON-snap version of Firefox 115.0.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.

I am already aware that the snap version of Firefox cannot see beyond the Home directory. I installed the non-SNAP Firefox using Terminal by downloading the DEB file and I completed all the steps to prioritize updates from Mozilla Team PPA.

I have Google Drive files enabled from Accounts within Ubuntu settings. I can see Google Drive mounted in Ubuntu. I can modify Google Drive files from Files in Ubuntu. However, when I try to save files from Firefox, Google Drive does not show up as a location. I have several other disks mounted to my system and they show up as locations but Google Drive is missing.

To clarify, I've included screenshots of what I can see from Files and what I can see from Firefox (below).

I have another Ubuntu machine setup the same way and I have no problems saving files from Firefox to Google Drive.

I am quite sure it is not a snap problem. In the past, I had the obvious issues with the snap version of Firefox. However, in that case I was still able to see Google Drive from within Firefox but the files did not show up when I attempted to save them to that location. In this case, the Google Drive location does not show up at all.

Any suggestions?

**What I see from Files (showing Google Drive)**

[Apparently I'm not allow to post pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmyaN.png)

**What I see from Firefox (missing Google Drive)**

[Apparently I'm not allow to post pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itMen.png)

**What I see under "other locations" in Firefox**

[Firefox other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITYIQ.png)

Comment: I just tested this out on my Xubuntu 22.04 installation.  I am using the non-snap version of Firefox as well.  I am able to see my Google Drive without a problem and start to download to it.  My Google Drive shows up as my gmail email address.

Comment: Thanks Terrance, I added some screenshots from Files and Firefox to show what I can see from each. Also, I double checked from System Monitor that I am not using the SNAP version.

Comment: In the second screenshot you have here, is your Google Drive not under Other Locations?

Comment: It's not, I just posted another screenshot of that. I can see my extra 100 GB SSD exFAT partition but not Google Drive. I even tried to initiate Google Drive by navigating to it from Files before going to Firefox.